# How to return a result (startActivityForResult) from a TabHost Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have 3 classes in my example:
Class A, the main activity.  Class A calls a startActivityForResult:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, "STRING");
```

Class B, this class is a TabActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassC.class);
tabHost.addTab...
```

Class C, this class is a regular Activity:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
intent.putExtra("SOMETHING", "EXTRAS");
this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

onActivityResult is called in Class A, but the resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELED` instead of `RESULT_OK` and the returned intent is null.  How do I return something from the Activity inside a TabHost?

I realize that the problem is that my Class C is actually running inside of Class B, and Class B is what is returning the `RESULT_CANCELED` back to Class A.  I just don't know a work around yet.

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Oh, god! After spending several hours and downloading the Android sources, I have finally come to a solution.

If you look at the Activity class, you will see, that `finish()` method only sends back the result if there is a `mParent` property set to `null`. Otherwise the result is lost.

```
public void finish() {
    if (mParent == null) {
        int resultCode;
        Intent resultData;
        synchronized (this) {
            resultCode = mResultCode;
            resultData = mResultData;
        }
        if (Config.LOGV) Log.v(TAG, "Finishing self: token=" + mToken);
        try {
            if (ActivityManagerNative.getDefault()
                .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData)) {
                mFinished = true;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    } else {
        mParent.finishFromChild(this);
    }
}
```

So my solution is to set result to the parent activity if present, like that:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
 [...]
if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
} else {
    getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
finish();
```

I hope that will be helpful if someone looks for this problem workaround again.

Comment: I posted a hacky solution here, its simple and involves a transparent activity with no contents - it gets normal lifecycle functions and makes everything easier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812120/android-onactivityresult-never-called/7815357#7815357

Comment: I used your solution, still my code is not catching the onactivityresult method when coming back. please help me..
do i need to use any thing else?

Comment: Why is returning a result in an Activity not documented anywhere in the API guides, struck me as odd.

Comment: thank you for your awesome job, just one thing, I wanna use this method in my onBackPressed override method too, but I Can't, do you know why? I cant use finish() in onBack and when I don't use its data and result code will be null in the A activity, do you know how can I Do such thing?

Answer (score 64):

http://tylenoly.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/how-to-finish-activity-with-results/

With a slight modification for "param_result"

```
/* Start Activity */
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setClassName("com.thinoo.ActivityTest", "com.thinoo.ActivityTest.NewActivity");
    startActivityForResult(intent,90);
}
/* Called when the second activity's finished */
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 90:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle res = data.getExtras();
            String result = res.getString("param_result");
            Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void finishWithResult()
{
    Bundle conData = new Bundle();
    conData.putString("param_result", "Thanks Thanks");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(conData);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Simple, `setResult` was the main thing. Set it to something, or a value for example `RESULT_OK` and you are good to go; `setResult(RESULT_OK);`. Helped me, +1

Answer (score 16):

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT?

> If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an
>   existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be
>   transfered to the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a onActivityResult in Class B as well and launch Class C using startActivityForResult. Once you get the result in Class B then set the result there (for Class A) based on the result from Class C. I haven't tried this out but I think this should work.

Another thing to look out for is that Activity A should not be a singleInstance activity. For startActivityForResult to work your Class B needs to be a sub activity to Activity A and that is not possible in a single instance activity, the new Activity (Class B) starts in a new task.

Comment: Since Class B is a TabActivity and Class C is a Tab in that activity you cannot do a startActivityForResult in Class B.

None of my activities are Single Instance Activities.

Answer (score -1):

For start Activity 2 from  Activity 1 and get result, you could use startActivityForResult and implement onActivityResult in Activity 1 and use setResult in Activity2.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra(NUMERO1, numero1);
intent.putExtra(NUMERO2, numero2);
//startActivity(intent);
startActivityForResult(intent, MI_REQUEST_CODE);
```