# TabActivity and startAcitivtyForResult

Tags: android

can I make TabActivity start it's childs activities for result? 
I need it because I can't make result code from a tab to propagate all 
the way up in the chain (it's reset in the TabActivity) 
thanks, 
Ori

Comment: this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity

Answer (score 1):

All Activities are subclass of Activity Classes. so everything an Activity do is possible for all.

Comment: in other words, you're suggestion I should extend TabActivity?