# How to startactivityforresult in tab child of TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity

I have `TabHost` with tab child like this:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("web")
            .setIndicator("web")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, webview.class)));
```

In `WebView` class, I startactivityforresult:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Webview.this,EventManage.class),GET_CODE);
```

In Eventmanage class, I set result but can not capture result in webview class.

Anybody can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an onActivityResult() method in your webview class. See  [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this: [How to return a result (startActivityForResult) from a TabHost Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)