# startActivityForResult annoying behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I have the following case

When press a button I startActivityForResult , it opens another activity with dialog theme and show a list of linear layouts, and when I press on the linear layout I finish the activity on the onClick Listener

but the onActivityResult method never called

so can anyone help in this ??

EDIT: Adding code

Activity that open the dialog activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DATA_LIST_KEY, myDataList);
startActivityForResult(intent, 5000);
```

onClick Listener

```
public void onClick(View v) {

   setResult(5000);
   SecondActivity.this.finish();                        
}
```

EDIT 2

I have found the following

1- I'm using TabActivity to add tabs to all my activities, now The onActivityResult fire on the TabActivity but doesn't fire in the sub activities inside it

Can any one help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the reason of this problem, I was using TabActivity and using activities as tabs and the onActivityResult called but in the parent activity that hold all other activities and I have solved it by handling it in the parent activity

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call `setResult(intent)` method in the second activity after clicking the item.

*Edit 1:*
I think you set the result in a wrong way. It should be an intent with either Result_OK or Reuslt_Cancel.

Edit 2- Example:

```
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra(key, val);
setResult(RESULT_OK, output)
```

Comment: Yes I set the result with the same code that I used to open the activity

Answer (score 0):

Hints to check:

1. You call setResult **before** finish().
2. Remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or `android:noHistory` for your activity if present

Comment: Yes I call setResult before calling finish, and I didn'y add android:launchMode="singleInstance" or android:noHistory to my manifest file

Comment: then, your code looks fine, I would actually call SecondActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK), this 5000 will be returned as request code in onActivityResult

Comment: Why do you need `SecondActivity.this.` anyway?

Comment: because the code is inside OnClick Listener, so I prefer to make sure that I'm accessing the right object, and I think this is not the problem here

Comment: You have added info that you are using TabActivity - look into this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556684/issue-with-onactivityresult-in-tab-activity