# How to get activity result from an Activity in a TabHost?

Tags: android

In my application, Activity A will start a TabActivity, and the TabActivity has some Activity in its content.

```
tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent( new Intent(this, ActivityB.class ) ) ...
```

And ActivityB will get some data from user(i.e pick a contact), and i want ActivityA will get these data. But as you see, it seems I cannot startyActivityForResult and onActivityResult to get result.

So, how can i get data in ActivityA from ActivityB ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again there's no answer to my question. So i have to solve it myself. My solution is ugly but worked. As somebody can guess, we can write a singleton class to store these data. ActivityB will write data and ActivityA will read it. Very easy.

In contrast, i searched in this site, and found some simple solution. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for the object you want to store (ie: ObjectYouWantToStore).

Extend the android.app.Application.

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {

private ObjectYouWantToStore mObject;

public ObjectYouWantToStore getObject() {;
    return mObject;
}

public void setObject(ObjectYouWantToStore obj) {
    mObject = obj;
}

}
```

Write in the manifest file the path to the Application.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MyApp">
```

Store the data in your activity B

```
MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplicationContext();
app.setObject(ObjectYouWantToStore);
```

Access the same data in your activity A

```
MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplicationContext();
ObjectYouWantToStore obj = app.getObject();
```