# How to start a searchable activity for result using a search dialog

Tags: java, android

does anyone know how to start a searchable activity using the method "startActivityForResult()"? I've a activity - A with a search dialog and pressed 'Go' it summons a another acitvity in this B, the B activity will perform some query and should return the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is two questions.

This link is a previous question that explains how to send and receive intends using startActivityForResult:

[How to return a result (startActivityForResult) from a TabHost Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)

If you want to know how to implement your activity "B", you're going to need to provide more information.