# Problem with onClickListener

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

this actually does nothing when i click the button.
The button is like:

```
Button Confirmar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btConfirma);

Confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String Login = edLogin.getText().toString();
        String Senha = edSenha.getText().toString();
        if(Login.length() == 0 || Senha.length() ==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getuser.this, "Por favor preencha o login e a senha!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (chkKeep.isChecked() && (edLogin.getText().toString() != Settings.getUser() || edSenha.getText().toString() != Settings.getPass())) {
            Settings.setUser(edLogin.getText().toString());
            Settings.setPass(edSenha.getText().toString());
            Settings.setKeepUser(chkKeep.isChecked());
            jXML.updateConfigXml();             
        }
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bD = new Bundle();
        bD.putStringArray("Login", new String[] {edLogin.getText().toString(), edSenha.getText().toString()});
        i.putExtras(bD);
        finishActivity(555);
    }
});
```

As asked --> Button XML:

```
 <Button android:layout_width="180dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btOkLogin" android:text="Confirmar"></Button>
```

**SOLVED:** Had to use setResult(ResulCode, Intent) before finish();
Answered by: @Sam-Quest

Comment: verify `Button` 's id and debug your method by writing `Log.d("Confirmar","onClick");` inside `onClick()`

Comment: what are you doing with the intent

Comment: I'm trying to get username and password for other intent. Just two strings, but i have a config XML that stores the user and password if the chkBox is marked.

Comment: Could we have the xml where the button is defined as well?

Comment: Roman, it's at the question, edited it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you have to set the result before calling the finish

```
...
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle bD = new Bundle();
bD.putStringArray("Login", new String[] {edLogin.getText().toString(), edSenha.getText().toString()});
i.putExtras(bD);

setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

finishActivity(555);
```

check this link if you have any doubt. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on first line inside onClick listener, run on debug mode and see where it goes on the code.

Comment: It doesn't call the onclicklistener. When i click the damn button, nothing happens :(

Comment: Yes it is. The button have default properties, besides TEXT and ID of course.

Comment: Is findViewById(R.id.btConfirma) returning a valid View object?

Comment: Solved? Didn't you say it was not calling onClickListener? :P

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange error. I'd try to maybe `setOnClickListener(this)` and let your activity implement `onClick(View)`. Otherwise you can add `android:onClick` tag to the xml button object.