# Pass results from child activity to Parent Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I have 6 activities in my app which are Activity1, Activity2, TabActivity, childTab1, childtab2, ExtraActivity.

App flow:

```
Activity1 => Activity2 => TabActivity =>ChildTab1 or ChildTab2 => ExtraActivity
```

Now i want to pass some data from `ExtraActivity` to `Activity1`. I am using `StartActivityForResult` for starting all activities.

`ExtraActivity` is able to send data to `ChildTab1` or `ChildTab2` but i unable to send that data back to `TabActivity` and further back to `Activity2` and finally to `Activity1`.

Please help!!

**Update:** While searching, i got my solution via this post:

[How to return a result (startActivityForResult) from a TabHost Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)

Comment: i am using intents only.. it was so obvious that's why i didn't mention that. The problem is that you cant define startactivityForResult when you add a tab in tabactivity.. may be thats why the intent set in setResult is getting lost.

Comment: use start activity and use putString() .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delegate the onActivityResult method-result from ChildTabX to TabActivity with ((TabActivity)getParent()).onActivityResult(). There you just call setResult and finish() again to send the result to Activity2. Same for Activity2

Answer (score 0):

You could use the application context to pass data between activites.

Way to use app context.

Extend the application class and add the attributes as you require. So in your activity you can access the application context and get the data. As the application context is a singleton it will be the same instance in every activity.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
appContext.myString = "YOUR DATA;
```

In any other activity you can access that bitmap the same way.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
```

Now the string is in the appContext object.

You also need to add

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

to application tag in the manifest file.