# OnActivityResult is not called if new Activity is started in result activity

Tags: android

I've got three activities.

First start the second with startActivityForResult,
Second starts third, sets result and finish itself.

However first activity doesn't trigger onActivityResult.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

When you start the second activity set the flag on the intent with:

public static final int **FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT**
Since: API Level 1

If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, then the reply target of the existing activity will be transfered to the new activity. This way the new activity can call setResult(int) and have that result sent back to the reply target of the original activity.
Constant Value: 33554432 (0x02000000)

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to rewrite this using Fragments, that have great control over backstack.