# How invoke another activity on taking a picture with custom Camera Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-imageview

I implemented a Camera Application with the help of some of the tutorials available in internet.

And I am able to take pictures, saving them in a separate directory and storing the information in my own database. In this case I am not showing any preview of the Image to the user.

Now my requirement is to show a Image Preview with Save and Cancel buttons after taking the picture. For achieving this, I created another activity with `ImageView` and Buttons.

And in my main Activity I am doing the following.

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
});
........    
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyCameraActivity.this, SaveOrDiscardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LOC_ATTRS", new double[]{dLatitude, dLongitude});
            intent.putExtra("IMG_DATA", imageData);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
            camera.startPreview();          
        }
    };
```

In my `SaveOrDiscardActivity` class I am getting the data and putting it in the `ImageView`.
I am able to see the Preview properly.

Now I have the following questions.

1) Is it good approach to call another activity from `onPictureTaken` method ?

2) After clicking on the Camera Button it is taking some measurable time(2 to 5 seconds) to go to the another activity. How to fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke Camera by using following code:

```
Intent cameraIntent1 = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

File cameraImagefolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/phimages/");

if (!cameraImagefolder.isDirectory()) 
{
   cameraImagefolder.mkdirs();
 }  
 File file = new File(cameraimagename);
 Log.d("HI1", "camera image name" + cameraimagename);

 Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
 cameraIntent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent1, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Call your SaveOrDiscardActivity in onActivityForresult method.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(MyCameraActivity.this, SaveOrDiscardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LOC_ATTRS", new double[]{dLatitude, dLongitude});
            intent.putExtra("IMG_DATA", imageData);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
            camera.startPreview();      }
```

Comment: The `Intent` calling `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will launch the system's Camera App to take the picture.

Answer (score 0):

After I did a few research on `PictureCallback` as well as `Activity`, I found you might need to do a little bit change based on your code.

I assume that you need to use the `PictureCallback` to pass the picture data back to its parent activity, right?

If that's the case, you can first call your camera activity use `startActivityForResult`

Then, within your camera activity, use `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` method within `PictureCallback` like:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
        ...
        if(getParent() == null) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        } else {
            getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        }
        finish(); 
        ...
// If you don't call finish() here 
//The current activity won't be terminated, you'll stay in the camera preview 
//but not go back to the parent activity.         
    }
```

For your further reference, please check Android Developer's Official Site:
[Capture Picture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture) and
[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

And if you're facing problems that the parent can't get the result, please refer to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621390/763459