# I want to refer checkbox in another activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

In my application i am having checkboxes in first activity that i want to refer on second activity ***with its state information whether it is checked or unchecked***. is there any way to do this plz explain in detail with example .
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using intent to move from current activity to next activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bundle.

pass its checked or unchecked state to bundle and pass when another activity is started, for example.

```
Intnet i = new Intent(class.this, classb.class)
Bundle b = new Bundle();

if(button.ischecked()){
b.putInt("Checked", 1);
}else{
b.putInt("Checked", 0);
}
startActivity(i);
```

In antoher activity, get the bundle

```
int checked = b.getInt("Checked");

if(checked = 1){ Log.i("TAG", "It is checked")}
// perform action here......
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in traditional java style like that:

```
otherActivity.isSomeCheckboxCecked();
```

You have to implement some communication between activities. Simplest one is use

```
startActivityForResult()
```

Take a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)