# can we call startActivityForResult from adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

is it possible to have method `onActivityResume` within `adapter` & call `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: Yes, are you sure use startActivityForResult in Adapter

Comment: i have a list view that is getting its contents from adapter. I have a button in adapter,on click of button another activity will start & return something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity   its a complate example same as your quastion .i thing its helpfull..All the Best

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yes. Just pass the context of the activity to the adapter in the adapter's constructor (here stored as mContext). 
In getView, just call

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Comment: Thanks @user936414 .

Comment: How can we be sure that context here is always an instance of Activity?

Comment: @Asakura As mentioned in the answer "Just pass the context of the activity to the adapter in the adapter's constructor" - you need to pass the context of activity

Comment: But how if we want to get onActivityResult in Fragment instead of Activity ?

Answer (score 9):

Not necessarily pass to pass context in adapter's constructor. You can get context from parent ViewGroup. Sample for RecyclerView adapter:

```
 Context mContext;
 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        ...
    }
```

Sample for ListView BaseAdapter

```
 Context mContext;
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        ...
}
```

And use it wherever you want

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Comment: The Context does not have startActivityForResult? You need an Activity for that.

Comment: You can cast mContext to Activity for that: `((Activity) mContext)`

Comment: One problem I just discovered with this approach is if you are receiving the result in a Fragment it will not be delivered.  Even if you call super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in your activity it does not appear to deliver the result to your fragment.  In further reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment I found that you must make the call startActivityForResult without any Activity.  Thoughts?

Comment: It because of in this case you call `startActivityForResult()` from your Activity. If you need to receive result in Fragment, you need to call `startActivityForResult()` from Fragment.

Comment: But how if we want to call onActivityResult in Fragment like this case ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685955/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-in-fragment-where-intent-pass-from-adapter-c?noredirect=1#comment96166329_54685955

Answer (score 3):

```
//First Do
public Activity context;
public int REQUEST_CODE = 111;

public Adapter(Activity context, Data data) {
    this.context = context;
}

///Second Do
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}
```

If you follow this code then you don't need to write it - ((Activity) context) - every time, before - .startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); - when you use startActivityForResult in Adapter.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: What do i need to do if i want to get the result from Activity onActivityResult result back to  to the same Adapter postion, to update the UI (onBindViewHolder)

Comment: @Rahul.S see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015950/can-we-call-startactivityforresult-from-adapterhow-to-get-the-response - this link

Answer (score 2):

Offcource...

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 911);
```

Caution !!

Only pass **MyActivity.this** from activity to adapter as context.

Only pass **getActivity()**; from fragment to adapter as context.