# Need some code while using startActivityForResult in BaseAdapter of ListView for Attaching Image from gallery to current position of ListView

Tags: android, listview, onactivityresult

I have a `ListView` which contain `Button` & `ImageView`, when I click the button it should go to gallery & attach/assign image to `ImageView` at that position.

But there i am facing a problem , when I click on button,I am calling `startActivityForResult` from Adapter class & for that `onActivityResult` is in MainClass(because we can't write it in AdapterClass) where we call adapter. So lets say I know position of `ListView` then how can we assign image at that position?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015950/can-we-call-startactivityforresult-from-adapterhow-to-get-the-response check this link this may give some clue to get work on

Comment: Right way is to modify underlying the data and tell the adapter to refresh

Comment: @Madhu hi, calling a function which is in adapter that is fine,but after going their how to modify Image of ImageView of specific position of which we pressed button (we have position number,but how to modify that)

Comment: @Selvin isnt their any way by which just by knowing position we can change imageView content of that position ?

Comment: did you try with tabassum Latif answer, that  make sense

Comment: @Madhu currently looking for adapter.notifydatasetchanged but salvin's ans also working

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a model
2. Pass array of model to listAdapter
3. change the list when you get image from onActivityResult method
4. then call adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: does this adapter.notifydatasetchanged() works if we just edited (like `mItem.get(position).setImage(encodedImage)`)& not used add(),remove(),clear().Because it is giving me NullPointerExeption    asking because for ArrayAdapter it is mentioned that it works only for add(),remove() etc