# onActivityResult in RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I tried to open gallery from my adapter.

```
emp_photo_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                ((EmployeeActivity)context).startActivityForResult(i, 2017);
            }
        });
```

Then i want to show that choosen image into my `imageview` in my `recycycleview`, how to do that? Because i cant add `onActivityResult`on my `adapter`. Thanks in advance

> Edit

My Full Code

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ....

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ....

    }
    public void bind(final Employee item, final OnItemClickListener listener, final Context context) {
        ....
        generateDialog(item,dialog_employee);
        ....

    }

    ...
    ...
    void generateDialog(Employee item, View v){
        //Dialog child
        //Photo
        emp_photo_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                ((EmployeeActivity)context).startActivityForResult(i, 2017);
            }
        });
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: ok Then create a event listener using interface and implement it in RecycycleView to get selected image

Comment: actually i use `ViewHolder` and that makes that difficult to get data from outer class. could u give me an example?

Comment: See [Creating Custom Listeners](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)

Comment: i guess here you find your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015950/can-we-call-startactivityforresult-from-adapterhow-to-get-the-response

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: @satendra i use holder and because of that i cant just call some function in my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your result will arrive in `EmployeeActivity` in `onActivityResult`. Since you are picking an image, the result will be a `Uri` which you will have to retrieve first, then bind to the appropriate item. I suggest the following sequence of actions:

1. Create a new request code which stores the item position and identifies the request. If there are no other requests, you can simply make your row id your request code.
2. Get the `Uri` using `data.getData()` and remember your received request code. Make sure that the result code is `Activity.RESULT_OK`.
3. Feed the `Uri` and the request code (which contains the item id) to a `Loader` or something similar to retrieve the image.
4. Store the resulting image somewhere accessible for your `MyViewHolder` for the item id. For example, you can create a `Map` inside it which will store loaded images.
5. Find the position for the item id in the adapter and call `notifyItemChanged` on the adapter for the position received. You can call either `notifyItemChanged(int position)` to do a full rebind, or `notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)` where `payload` will be your bitmap.

Comment: how to send Uri to myviewholder?

Comment: @Huzain I would probably have a method like `void putLoadedBitmap(int itemId, @NonNull Bitmap bitmap)` on `MyViewHolder`, and it would store the bitmap internally in a map.

Comment: yeah, then how to call that method? myviewholder is inside myadapter. I tried to call any method, but i dont know how to call that method in myviewholder that was inside myadapter

Comment: @Huzain Sorry, I meant that you need to create a method on the adapter, and the view holder can hold a reference to the adapter to get the bitmaps.

Comment: could u please give me an example that method?

Comment: @Huzain The method will just have a line like `itemBitmapsMap.put(itemId, bitmap)` in it, what's there to give an example for?

Comment: how to get reference in view holder to my adapter when i get call some method in adapter?

Comment: @Huzain Just get it in constructor and store it in a field (`MyViewHolder(View view, MyAdapter adapter)`), inside you call `this.adapter = adapter`.

Comment: i still didnt get it, sorry :(

Comment: @Huzain I'm afraid you'll have to brush up on Java basics in that case, I can't write the code for you.

Comment: i know what r u trying to tell me, but actually what i dont know is how to call method in viewholder from activity that contain activity result?

Comment: @Huzain You don't need to call anything in the view holder, you just invalidate the adapter, and the view holders will do the binding again, this time with the loaded bitmap. I hope you can access the adapter from the activity.

Comment: @Huzain That's what step 5 does.