# My startActivityForResult is asking for 3 mandatory parameters

Tags: android-intent, android-recyclerview, startactivityforresult

My startActivityForResult is asking for 3 mandatory parameters: Activity, intent and the request code. I'm using Intent to call an activity from within a recycler view when a button is tapped. But when I type startActivityForResult, it is asking for 3 parameters. I don't understand what activity it is asking for and how to pass it.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: The answers to that question don't help me.

Comment: This is probably because you're using `AppCompat.startActivityForResult()` although the parameters is not 3 but 4

Comment: So how can I use the command that takes in just 2 arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the issue. I had to context the mainActivity. Since the adapter class is not an activity I have to pass the activity of the pare [for more assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015950/can-we-call-startactivityforresult-from-adapterhow-to-get-the-response/20016013)

Thank you for the help.