# Simple MVC in android; passing object to activities

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I have just recently started working with android development and I am trying to grasp a relatively simple concept I believe. Some background to the question first.

I had recently created a Java program using the MVC design pattern (the view and controller were linked though). In this project, I had a created my own class to be the model, and in my main() function, I simply created a single instance of this model class, which I then passed on to all of my other classes. This allowed every class (and therefore, every view) to have the same model object, and hence, all of the updates done to that model class by different controllers.

I am wondering how this would work in Android's activities? Is it possible for each activity to have a reference to the same, single model class object? For example, lets say I have an android application that has a home page with some stuff on it. On the home page, there is a button that lets you go to a "Settings" page, which starts a new activity that allows the user to change some settings. I would like to be able to pass the model object to the "Settings" activity, have the user make whatever changes are possible on the "Settings" activity, update the model accordingly, so that when I return to the home page, my model object contains these changes.

Is this possible? Am I simply overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the model structure. If the model is too complicated, I would make it a static singleton created by an Application class and obtain a reference from wherever I want.

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Or you can make the model Parcelable and pass it through intent. Which would be a bit more complicated.

To pass data to an Activity, you can use Parcelable or Serializable in Intent extras. To get the modified result, you can use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult.

http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

[How to return a result (startActivityForResult) from a TabHost Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497205/how-to-return-a-result-startactivityforresult-from-a-tabhost-activity)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html