# onActivityResult() is not being called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I've been trying for a while now to get this to work but to no avail. I am attempting to retrieve data from my DetailActivity and return it to my MainActivity. Can any one assist.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "KJHVLERHVRHOGVINORWUI " + MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY + " " + resultCode +" "+Activity.RESULT_OK);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case (MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    System.out.println("LOG_TAG"+ "MainActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH" + data.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        artistsAlbums = new ArrayList<>();
        tempAlbums = new ArrayList<>();

        final RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(END_POINT)
                .build();
        service = adapter.create(APIService.class);

        EditText tview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.artist_field);
        tview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                Log.v("LOG_TAG", s + " onTextChanged() " + " start: " + start + " count: " + count + " after: " + after);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { //aftertextchanged{
                Log.v("LOG_TAG", s + " afterTextChanged()");
                if (listViewRefresh) {
                    if (mAdapter != null) {
                        //mAdapter.clear();
                        //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        artistsAlbums.clear();
                        displayItems();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                name = s.toString();
                Log.v("LOG_TAG", s.length() + " onTextChanged() " + " start: " + start + " before: " + before + " count:" + count);
                //listViewRefresh = (start == 0) && (before == 1) && (count == 0);
                listViewRefresh = name.length() == 0;
                    //======================================A R T I S T S=====================================m============
                    service.searchArtists(name, new Callback<ArtistsPager>() {
                                @Override
                                public void success(ArtistsPager artistsPager, Response response) {
                                    Image image;
                                    if (artistsPager.artists.items != null) { //for .. 6
                                        artistsAlbums.clear(); //this line doesn't work!!
                                        //artistsAlbums = new ArrayList<ArtistsAlbum>(); //this line works but is wrong!!

                                        for (int i = 0; i < artistsPager.artists.items.size(); i++) { //for .. 1
                                            try {  // try .. 1
                                                mName = artistsPager.artists.items.get(i).name;         //Breakpoint here!!
                                                mId = artistsPager.artists.items.get(i).id;
                                                int size = artistsPager.artists.items.get(i).images.size();

                                                if (size == 0) {
                                                    //------------------------------------------
                                                    album = new ArtistsAlbum();
                                                    album.setName(mName);
                                                    album.setId(mId);
                                                    artistsAlbums.add(album);
                                                    //------------------------------------------
                                                } else {
                                                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                                                        if ((300 <= artistsPager.artists.items.get(i).images.get(j).width) &&
                                                            (650 >= artistsPager.artists.items.get(i).images.get(j).width)){
                                                            mUrl = artistsPager.artists.items.get(i).images.get(j).url;
                                                            album = new ArtistsAlbum();
                                                            album.setUrl(mUrl);
                                                            album.setName(mName);
                                                            album.setId(mId);
                                                            artistsAlbums.add(album);
                                                            break;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { //try .. 1
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }// for .. 1

                                        if (!listViewRefresh )
                                            displayItems();
                                        else {
                                            artistsAlbums.clear();
                                            displayItems();
                                        }

                                        //displayItems(artistsAlbums);

                                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "======================================= TOP ================================================");
                                        for (ArtistsAlbum obj : artistsAlbums)
                                            System.out.println("LOG_TAG" + "name: " + obj.getName() + " id: " + obj.getId() + " Url: " + obj.getUrl());
                                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "====================================== BOTTOM ==============================================");


                                        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                                                    int position, long id) {
                                                final ArtistsAlbum item = (ArtistsAlbum) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                                // System.out.println("LOG_TAG" + "name: " + item.getName() + " id: " + item.getId() + " Url: " + item.getUrl());
                                                //sendMessage(item.getId());
                                                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                                                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, item.getId());
                                                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SEARCH, name);
                                                startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY);


                                            }
                                        });
                                    } //for..6
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                                }
                    });
            } //onTextChanged
        });
}
```

Within DetailActivity I have my SetResult() within onPause() callback:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause   () {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPause()");
        Intent in = getIntent();
        in.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH, searchStr);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, in);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Activity.RESULT_OK" + in);
        finish();
    }
```

And for completeness I have supplied the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.richard.webapitest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.richard.webapitest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
           >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.richard.webapitest.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Many thank

addendum:
My Log Cat is as followed once run:

```
07-27 08:40:49.091    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/LOG_TAG﹕ onTextChanged()  start: 0 count: 0 after: 1
07-27 08:40:49.091    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/LOG_TAG﹕ 1 onTextChanged()  start: 0 before: 0 count:1
07-27 08:40:49.127    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/LOG_TAG﹕ e afterTextChanged()
07-27 08:40:49.515    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 318K, 4% free 9195K/9540K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
07-27 08:40:49.519    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17524: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17523: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
07-27 08:40:49.523    2080-2294/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
07-27 08:40:49.767    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/MainActivity﹕ in displayItems0
07-27 08:40:49.767    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/MainActivity﹕ ======================================= TOP ================================================
07-27 08:40:49.767    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/MainActivity﹕ ====================================== BOTTOM ==============================================
07-27 08:40:50.255    2080-2304/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 390K, 5% free 9319K/9736K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
07-27 08:40:50.275    2080-2304/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25K, 4% free 9352K/9736K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
07-27 08:40:50.275    2080-2304/com.example.richard.webapitest I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.036MB for 921612-byte allocation
07-27 08:40:50.283    2080-2094/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 10252K/10640K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
07-27 08:40:50.951    2080-2314/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 4% free 10257K/10640K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
07-27 08:40:50.959    2080-2314/com.example.richard.webapitest I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 11.604MB for 1638412-byte allocation
07-27 08:40:50.967    2080-2314/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 11857K/12244K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
07-27 08:40:51.431    2080-2098/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 4% free 11859K/12244K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
07-27 08:40:51.435    2080-2098/com.example.richard.webapitest I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.535MB for 974412-byte allocation
07-27 08:40:51.443    2080-2098/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 12810K/13196K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
07-27 08:40:51.723    2080-2099/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 3% free 12811K/13196K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
07-27 08:40:51.727    2080-2099/com.example.richard.webapitest I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 13.668MB for 1188552-byte allocation
07-27 08:40:51.743    2080-2099/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 13972K/14360K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
07-27 08:40:51.975    2080-2295/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 149K, 3% free 15041K/15448K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
07-27 08:40:52.187    2080-2295/com.example.richard.webapitest D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 3% free 16641K/17052K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
07-27 08:40:59.359    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-27 08:41:05.459    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/DetailActivity﹕ onPause()
07-27 08:41:05.459    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest V/DetailActivity﹕ Activity.RESULT_OKIntent { cmp=com.example.richard.webapitest/.DetailActivity (has extras) }
07-27 08:41:05.539    2080-2080/com.example.richard.webapitest W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: What does your logcat show?

Comment: Looks ok. Are you sure onPause() is getting called?

Comment: Hello vilpe89 here is the log cat for your perusal once the code is run.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I have placed logs throughout my code including onPause() and it being called,yes.

Comment: Maybe there is any problem in the app lifecycle when calling setResult from onPause. I would try to do the same thing in a button listener and check what happens then.

Comment: Instead of: Intent in = getIntent(); Rather try the following: Intent in = new Intent(); . . .

Comment: Hello,Smashing I've already tried that. It's the same result. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure the searchStr isn't null when you are puting it in the intent?

Comment: No it isn't as I've already attempted to test for this, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() 
{ 
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPause()");
   Intent data = new Intent();
   data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH, searchStr);
   if (getParent() == null) { 
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
   } else { 
      getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
   } 
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Activity.RESULT_OK" + in);
   super.onPause(); 
}
```

check also that https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621390/2401265

Comment: You missed the finish() method call

Comment: No vipe89 the finish() method is in onPause(). Thanks.

Comment: remove also the line         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: Hello gmetax the link you gave me helped I am now on the right track,thank you. This goes out to all the others who responded and helped.

Comment: if i have helped you, please approve my answer